# How do I iterate through the types that implement a trait

Tags: rust, metaprogramming

I am dealing with currencies.

I want to be able to parse them from ticker symbols like "USD".

I have implemented a currency trait which I want to have a compile time ticker symbol.

I want to iterate through all the types that implement Currency to check if their ticker symbol is equal to the string being parsed. If so, I want to return a type of that currency.

I have this so far:

```
pub trait Currency {
    const TICKER_SYMBOL: String;
}

#[derive(debug)]
struct USD;
impl Currency for USD { const TICKER_SYMBOL:  String = "USD".to_string();}

impl FromStr for dyn Currency {
    type Err = &'static str;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't anything like that. You'd have to create a collection yourself to iterate through.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want to express the different currencies in the type system? Why not something like `struct Currency { ticker_symbol: String }`?

Comment: I would recommend using an enum over a trait for having different currencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [strum crate](https://docs.rs/strum/0.20.0/strum/) + enums gave me what I wanted.

```
use std::str::FromStr;
use strum_macros::EnumString;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, EnumString)]
enum Currency {
    USD,
    BTC
}

#[test]
fn parses_currencies() {
    let c = Currency::from_str("USD");
    assert_eq!(Ok(Currency::USD), c);
    let err = Currency::from_str("monopoly money");
    assert!(err.is_err());
}
```